Is there a way to differentiate old and new PCOMM emulator?
I have 2 sessions open and both ended up having the same Session ID: "A".

Personal Communications iSeries Access for Windows (old session). Version: 5.7 for Windows
IBM i Access Client 5250 Emulator (new session). Version: 1.1.9.3

VBA code:
Set aPS = New AutPSTypeLibrary.AutPS
aPS.SetConnectionByName ("A")
aPS.GetText(18, 7, 4)
aPS.SetText "X123", 18, 7

What is happening:
SetText is getting invoked only on new session.
GetText is getting invoked only on old session.
What I tried:

Session ID only exists in old session: It won't work at all
Session ID only exists in new session: It won't work at all
Old and new session with same session ID: Get work on old session. Set work on new session.

Note: I recently installed EHLLAPI to connect the Excel VBA and the new session but before this, I had no issue with the old session.
So how can I control it so that the VBA will work correctly even if both sessions have the same name?
Edit: I uninstall the EHLLAPI and it is now working again for old session only. Hopefully, someone can help so that it will work with the old and new session.
